# Expected view to be called with URL keyword "pk" added "pk" to urls.py

Tags: python, django

Getting the error:

`AssertionError at /update_profile/ Expected view UpdateProfileView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the` .lookup_field`attribute on the view correctly.`

when I try to update a user profile.

Here is my urls.py

```
   path('update_profile/', views.UpdateProfileView.as_view(), name='update_profile'),
```

My UpdateProfileView:

```
class UpdateProfileView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
# permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
# authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
# lookup_field = 'username'
queryset = User.objects.all()
serializer_class = UpdateUserSerializer

@action(detail=True, methods=['put'])
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user.id)
```

UpdateUserSerializer

```
class UpdateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        #add 'city', 'country', 'bio'
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name']

        def validate_email(self, value):
            user = self.context['request'].user
            if User.objects.exclude(pk=user.pk).filter(email=value).exists():
                raise serializers.ValidationError({"email": "This email is already in use."})
            return value

        def validate_username(self, value):
            user = self.context['request'].user
            if User.objects.exclude(pk=user.pk).filter(username=value).exists():
                raise serializers.ValidationError({"username": "This username is already in use."})
            return value

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            user = self.context['request'].user

            if user.pk != instance.pk:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({"authorize": "You don't have permission for this user."})

            instance.first_name = validated_data['first_name']
            instance.last_name = validated_data['last_name']
            instance.email = validated_data['email']
            instance.username = validated_data['username']
            # instance.profile.city = validated_data['city']
            # instance.profile.country = validated_data['country']
            # instance.profile.bio = validated_data['bio']

            instance.save()

            return instance
```

I added the URL argument pk to my urls.py

```
path('update_profile/<int:pk>', views.UpdateProfileView.as_view(), name='update_profile')
```

This returns the error `page not found at update_profile`

Comment: Just make sure the user exists with the `pk` you passed to the URL

Comment: `def perform_update(self, serializer, pk):`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem getting the error Page not found (404)
Request Method: PUT
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/update_profile/

Comment: @Emm: but you should visit this with `/update_profile/42` with `42` the primary key of the item to update.

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem I get the error perform_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'
when I try to update a profile even after adding a user_id to my url